# Keeping quotation marks when using JSON parse

Tags: javascript, json, typescript

I've been unable to phrase this question in a way when searching which yields any results, so forgive me if there is an obvious place this has been asked.

I'd like all quotation marks to remain in my JSON when converting from a string.

My UI has a text field (string) which a user will type some JSON which will look something like this:

```
{ "example": "example" }
```

I'd like all the quotation marks to remain in my JSON object. However, when I run JSON.parse() on the above string, I get the following:

```
{ example: "example" }
```

How can I keep the quotation from being removed?

Comment: First of all, why do you want so? Quotes are not neccessary.

Comment: They are necessary in this case as the backend is expecting them, and it returns an error without

Comment: So you're sending it as a string yes?

Comment: No I'm forming a request from a bunch of fields on a form. Most of these fields are strings or numbers, however, one of the fields is expecting valid JSON. This request is then sent as JSON.

Comment: Ok, but stil, you're sending it via HTTP, so as a string. Your problem is definitely not clear. Please update your question with more specific information. Looks like you need JSON.stringify

Comment: The problem actually seems to be deeper in our codebase, there's a lot of flip flopping between strings/JSON objects and I think it's getting messed up during these conversions. Apologies for this question and taking everyones time.

Comment: Please make sure to construct a [mre]. Note that all three of those words are important: it should be an *example* only, you should not post your entire actual code, rather you should create a simplified example that demonstrates your problem. Also, it should be *minimal*, i.e. it should not contain anything that is not absolutely required to demonstrate the problem. (Most beginner problems can be demonstrated in less than 5 short simple lines of code.) And it should be *reproducible*, which means that if I copy&paste and run the code, I should see the exact same problem you see.

Comment: https://idownvotedbecau.se/toomuchcode/ https://idownvotedbecau.se/nomcve/

Answer (score 1):

A javascript object, which is what JSON.parse() returns, is not json. You don't need the quotes in an object (unless there are special characters in the property name) and can access that property with or without quotes in your code

```
const myObj = { example: "example" };
```

Both of the following are valid

```
console.log(myObject.example)
console.log(myObject["example"])
```

When you JSON.stringify() this again it will have valid quotes in the json string and be:

```
{ "example": "example" }
```

Comment: I think I should've added a little more context. The JSON that is being generated from this text field, will be part of a request that is sent to the backend.

Comment: That's fine, when you stringify this it will have the quotes to be valid json. You seem to be confusing actual objects with json. JSON.parse() returns an actual object

Comment: The problem actually seems to be deeper in our codebase, there's a lot of flip flopping between strings/JSON objects and I think it's getting messed up during these conversions. Apologies for this question and taking everyones time.

Answer (score 0):

`JSON.parse()` returns a *javascript object*, so the results you are getting are correct.

Your backend needs a *JSON string*, not a javascript object, so you need to `JSON.stringify()` your javascript object to obtain the JSON string that your backend requires.

```js
let userinput = '{ "example": "example" }';
let userobject = JSON.parse(userinput);
let resultjson = JSON.stringify(userobject);

console.log(userinput);
console.log(userobject);
console.log(resultjson);
```

produces

> { "example": "example" }
> { example: 'example' }
> {"example":"example"}

Comment: When I do this, it puts quotation marks around the curly braces, which I don't want.

Comment: @Sithling  It sounds like you haven't explained your problem correctly in the question then. Provide a [mcve] that demonstrates your actual issue

Comment: The problem actually seems to be deeper in our codebase, there's a lot of flip flopping between strings/JSON objects and I think it's getting messed up during these conversions. Apologies for this question and taking everyones time.